# Gravity Forms is validating hidden fields, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, validation, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a page with four fields on it A B C and D.  These each have their own conditional logic which decides whether they should be shown or hidden.  When a user reaches this page and, say, field B is displayed while the others are hidden, and the user enters something into field B and clicks Next, they receive:

**There was a problem with your submission. Errors have been highlighted below.**

But field B is not highlighted as it was validated just fine.  Viewing the source, however, I find that fields A C and D are displaying the **This field is required.** validation error.  But these fields are hidden...

I have tried changing themes to stock WP 2014 and deactivating all other plugins, this does not resolve the issue.  I am running the latest WP and GF.  What could possibly be the issue?  I've contacted GF's priority support and have not received a response.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with the gravity plugin, but I would assume that it does not validate disabled inputs. So try something like `<input type="hidden" disabled="disabled" value="value" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not perfect but I ended up hooking into `gform_validation` to manually validate the affected fields.